# What was used to pay taxes in Medieval England

Tags: middle-ages, economy, money

Was coinage issued by the Kings (Queen) used to pay taxes in Medieval England?

If so were these silver or gold coins or base metal ?

And how did the use of tally sticks fit into the tax system

Comment: Depends on the tax in question... there were many types and some were made in kind. Please explain how the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_medieval_England) failed to answer your question. Medieval England span centuries and [many types of coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Coins_of_England) were issued. As for tally sticks, if [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_stick#Split_tally_in_England) doesn't answer your question, please explain clearly why.

Comment: I upvoted assuming that it wasn't as trivial as you might imagine to search for such a thing. But if there is on wikipedia a specific article about "taxation in medieval england", then I might agree this is too trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on dozens of different factors.  If you did a quick review of wikipedia and google before asking the question, you could have answered most of your questions, identified the factors and been able to ask a far better question.

Most of the time taxes were paid in kind (chickens, grain, etc.) Other taxes were paid in labor - time spent laboring in the lord's field or building his roads, or other required service.  Most people didn't have any coin. (I don't have a source, but I remember one village in England where a single coin was used to settle all debts in the village on a single day; in technical terms, the supply of money was small, but the velocity of money was huge for one day out of the year).  You may also want to research "rose rent".  There were different tax customs for towns, nobles, yeomen, and other special categories.

[Trivial](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS581US581&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=medieval%20coins%20in%20england)  [research](https://finds.org.uk/medievalcoins) on google will answer that English coins were usually [silver](https://finds.org.uk/medievalcoins); [gold coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_penny) were rare.

[Tally sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_stick) are essential; if you don't have zero or algebra keeping accounts is fiendishly difficult.  Tally sticks and tally cloths are tools to help keep accounts.

You've opened a fascinating topic, but as it stands the question is both trivial and broad.  Can you ask another question that narrows down the scope of what you want to know?

Comment: You realize that this answer is very commentary... :)

Comment: Guilty as charged. I get annoyed at questions with insufficient research. Rather than whine about it, I tried to respond constructively. Apparently I still have some work to do</wry>.

Comment: Actually gold was only used as tender by monarchs and rich noblemen; silver for every day expenses of merchants and less wealthy noblemen; and copper pennies, halpennies and farthings for ordinary freemen. Serfs and villeins mostly paid in kind or in labour as you note.. With a labourer's daily wage in the vicinity of a single copper penny, it is clear why fractions of such were so common.

Comment: Here's a link to the attempt by Edward III in 1351 to revert wages to those in effect five years earlier, before the devastation of the Black Death: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_Labourers_1351. Note the denomination of daily wages in English copper pence(abbreviated d)